# How to one child element from being read by Screen Read when aria-live is used on parent?

Tags: html, accessibility

I have below mentioned HTML structure.

```
<div class="Parent Class" aria-live="assertive">
    <p class="child1"> Some text here </p>
    <div class="filters">
        <ul>
        <li> Filter 1</li>
        <li> Filter 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data inside the `<p>` tag gets changed on an action somewhere else in the code.
Now when the data inside `<p>` changes, the screen reader announces both `<p>` and the `<div class="filters">` elements.
How can I stop screen readers from announcing `<div class="filters">` element.

Note: I cannot use `aria-hidden="true"` on `<div class="filters">` as I still need it announced from the normal flow of screen reader.

Comment: remove the `aria-live="assertive"` from the parent and  put the `aria-live="assertive"` onto the `<p class="child1">` element and try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the <p> tag is getting generated from JS that's why I missed it in the HTML file. I will give it a try.